# Finding a seed that generates the same random numbers

Tags: python-3.x, random, random-seed

I've been thinking about an interesting problem and want to figure out how to solve it.

I want to find a `seed` that generates the same random numbers, specifically I want find a seed that the first random.getrandombits(32) will be equal to some value in the function `3x + 1` with the domain `1<=x<=99`.

For example: I want to find a seed `i` in which for some index `j` `random.getrandombits(32) == (the 3j + 1th generation of) random.getrandbits(32)`

I've tried bruteforcing it in python but that didnt go so well. Here's the script I have so far:

```
import random, sys

# Find seed in the range of 1-1,100000000
for i in range(1,100000000):
    random.seed(i)
    # Get first random number
    first = random.getrandbits(32)
    print("In {}".format(i))
    # Test for first 100 numbers
    for j in range(100):
            if (j != 0): random.getrandbits(32)
            current = random.getrandbits(32)
            # Found seed in which it occurs
            if (current == first):
                    print(i,j)
                    sys.exit(0)
            random.getrandbits(32)
    print("Done {}".format(i))
```

Comment: The whole point of a random number generator is to be unpredictable. The better the random number generator, the harder it is to predict the affect of the seed on the sequence. Python's is very good.